# database connection through spring boot in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am connecting spring boot application to PostgreSQL database. I have created the table using "create query tool" of PostgreSQL. It has been put in the default public schema. But when I tried to insert values in table, it does not accept values.

I have used the following command:

```
 Insert into User values(1,"ABC","pass_1");
```

What is the proper way to insert?

Comment: please specify the full error. eg "user" is a bad name for table already, and mixed case requires double quotes. so the answer depends on statement you used to create table and exact statement you use to insert

Comment: There's not enough to go on here.  Typically when one uses Spring Boot they're also using Hibernate or some ORM layer, so JDBC and pure SQL are normally not discussed.  It would be useful for you to explain what your project looks like, including whether or not you're making use of Spring JPA or where this SQL statement even *lives*.